# Why takes clearing swap soo long?

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, kernel, swap

Can someone explain me, why is move from RAM to swap fast and from swap to RAM very slow?

When I run program that needs more memory that is available, I see that the RAM is prety quickly "cleaned" by moving unsused (=the least accessed) pages to swap.

But then when I run

```
swapoff -a ; swapon -a
```

it takes really long time (minutes for multiple GBs of swap) to move the swap back to RAM.

The swap is in addition on SSD. Or do the `swapoff -a` command some special check, that I can avoid/disable?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually moving the pages to swap? It could be that the operating system just dropped a whole bunch of cached data (disk buffers etc...).

Comment: Yes, try it yourself. I tested it in VM. 4 GB RAM and 4 GB swap. I launched one application for image editing with huge image, the total consumed RAM was about 6 GB. Around 3 GB was swapped out. Then close the app and the real memory usage (RAM+swap) will drop to the the system + other app usage (around 1 - 1.5 GB at my VM). Run the command above and it will take around minute to move the data from HDD to the RAM. The HDD is SSD in my situation.

Comment: This has been answered here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45673/how-can-swapoff-be-that-slow